# Is @DeclareRoles limited to Java Servlet classes?

Tags: security, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish, weblogic

I'm trying to get a clear understanding of where `@DeclareRoles` annotation can be used.  The API simply says:

> Used by application to declare roles. It can be specified on a class.

I've used `@DeclareRoles` successfully with GlassFish and Payara and for them I can put `@DeclareRoles` anywhere; it seems those EE servers will scan and find all usages.  I tried transferring some code to WebLogic 12.2.1 and started getting some role errors at deployment. I tracked the problem down to WebLogic wanting the `@DeclareRoles` annotation only on a Servlet class.

So should `@DeclareRoles` be able to put on any class and the GlassFish/Payara behavior is correct?  Or should `@DeclareRoles` be limited only to a Servlet class and the WebLogic behavior is correct.  Given WebLogic's history, I tend to think it's not doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java EE 7.0 & 8.0 Specifications, [javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/DeclareRoles.html) need only be supported by web containers and EJB containers.

In other words, the class that is annotated must be an EJB or a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this more, I found JSR-340, Servlet 3.1 specification, section 15.5.1 AND JSR-369, Servlet 4.0 specification, section 15.2.2 both state:

> The @DeclareRoles annotation may only be defined in classes
>   implementing the javax.servlet.Servlet interface or a subclass
>   thereof.

So, it looks like WebLogic got this right and GlassFish/Payara behavior is outside of the spec.

Comment: Remember that your web application may contain EJBs that can also have this annotation